# Mindstorms M.V.P. model doesn't move

Tags: mindstorms, programming, robot-inventor

I'm a total newbie to Mindstorms 51515.

I am trying to program my M.V.P. model and everything seems to work except the movement programming blocks (pink). Does anyone have a hint or a clue about what's wrong, before I go bonkers?

I use the latest version (10.4.2)
All motors are updated and calibrated.

Comment: First suggestion: are the wires fully pushed in to the ports on both the motors and the control unit? Second suggestion: did you plug the motors into the correct ports?

Comment: If this is a question about code, which doesn't work for you - please share the code.